# Why I can't pull the new code on the BitBucket repository? Says "Already up-to-date" but I have not all the pushed code

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-pull, git-remote

I am not so into **GIT** and I have the following problem that I can't underestand.

I am using a **BitBucket** repository where I am working with another person.

I tried to obtain the new code pushed by my coleegue, doing:

```
git pull
```

but it says to me:

```
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

But on the BitBucket repository (it is in the remote **master branch**, I can see it into the BitBucket website) there is some code that I have not on my local system.

So I tried to obtain the list of all the remote branches by:

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/GLIS-Trigger-TAG
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

So what exactly means? I am pointing to **origin/HEAD**? What it means? What exactly is **origin/HEAD**

Have I to switch on the **origin/master** branch to obtain this code?

What could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: What is the output of `git branch -avv`?

Comment: If nothing comes and you know there is code missing, you probably are in the wrong branch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several questions you've asked, and those questions suggest a little additional confusion.  So:

> So I tried to obtain the list of all the remote branches by:
>
> ```
> $ git branch -r
>   origin/GLIS-Trigger-TAG
>   origin/HEAD -> origin/master
>   origin/master
> ```
>
> So what exactly means? I am pointing to origin/HEAD? What it means? What exactly is origin/HEAD

What that means is that your local repo has "remote branch references" for a remote named `'origin`, and on that remote it sees branches named `master` and `GLIS-Trigger-TAG`.  The remote's default branch is `master` (which is what the `origin/HEAD` entry is saying).

None of this tells you where you are pointing.  Running `git branch` without the `-r` would list local branches, and if you're on a local branch then that branch's name will be preceded by a `*`.  You are never "on" a remote branch; if you `checkout` to a remote branch ref, you will be in detached head state (not on any branch), because local commits don't advance remote branch refs.

> Have I to switch on the origin/master branch to obtain this code?

No, as I noted trying to do this would put you in detached HEAD state (which is sometimes fine, but is not what you want here.)

My understanding is that you see the changes on the remote's `master` branch; so instead you need to switch to the *local* `master` branch - because most likely it's set up to track `origin/master`.  (It is by default, so for it to be otherwise you'd have had to deliberately set up a different configuration.)

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

You can also get updates to *all* remote refs by

```
git fetch
```

Then you would be able to check the "up-to-date" status of any branch in a number of ways, such as by checking a branch out and running

```
git status
```

or without having to check out branches by

```
git diff branch_name origin/branch_name
```

Answer (score 1):

From your terminal, just type

```
git branch
```

this will list all the branches and point out the branch you are currently in.

Check if it is master branch. If not then you should move to master branch to get the changes.

```
git checkout master
```

and then,

```
git pull
```

But on the other hand, you want the changes from master into the current branch, then there is no need to move to master, but rather use this command to get the changes in master branch to your current branch

```
git pull origin master
```